# android getContentResolver().insert() occasionally returning null

Tags: android

I have a piece of code that aims to launch the android camera, let the user take a photo and eventually keep the uri of the image once it is saved.

So far I have managed to get it working. However, it seems like a 50/50 chance that the app will crash with a NPE. I have no idea why this is happening

my code:

```
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

private void doTakePhotoAction() {
        String fileName = "temp.jpg";  
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
        mImageCaptureUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);  
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mImageCaptureUri, projection, null, null, null); 
        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
        intent.putExtra("image-path", capturedImageFilePath);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
}
```

The NPE error refers me back to the line

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mImageCaptureUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

and it is being thrown because `mImageCaptureUri` is null. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix / work around this or why this is in fact happening

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really have to take to heart the first rule of Android Activities: **Android may decide at *any* time to kill your activity**, resetting all member variables in the process. It will simply rebuild the activity once it needs to handle `onActivityResult`... but as you initialized `mImageCaptureUri` in your specific handler, it will now be *null*.

The classic cause in your example would be an **orientation change** during the launched "capture an image" activity (orientation changes will typically kill the activity), but there is a myriad of other reasons why android would decide to terminate it (lack of memory, incoming calls, phone having a bad hair day, etc).

The *solution* is to store and restore state like `mImageCaptureUri` in `onSaveInstanceState()`, and restore it in the `onCreate()` of the Activity, i.e.

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            mImageCaptureUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("imageCaptureUri");
        }
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        outState.putParcelable("imageCaptureUri", mImageCaptureUri);
    }
```

Comment: perfect answer. Thank you! - just tested it and it works great